# Compiler does not unbox lambda parameter int

Tags: java, lambda, type-inference, unboxing

So i'm trying to pass a Function to perform an operation on a int[x] value.

So this is my method:

```
public void apply(int index, UnaryOperator<Integer> func) {
    V[index] = func.apply(V[index]);
}
```

This works:

```
register.apply(0, new UnaryOperator<Integer>() {

                @Override
                public Integer apply(Integer x) {
                    return x & 6;
                }

            });
```

and this works:

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> func = x -> x & 6;
register.apply(0, func);
```

But this gives me a compile error:

```
register.apply(0, x -> x & 6);
```

> "Operator & can not be applied to java.lang.Object, int"

The compiler doesn't seem to be able to infer the type, even though it is defined in the method declaration `UnaryOperator<Integer>`

What am i missing? am i blind? or does this just not work in java?

I'm using intellij CE edition 2019.1.2 and OpenJDK 11.0.1 on a macbook.

Comment: Wouldn't an `IntUnaryOperator` be better for an `int[]`?

Comment: I was not aware of that interface RealSkeptic, and yes it worked! thank you! still wondering why the above example didn't.

Comment: Can you post the full source? Both cases work for me...

Comment: Since you didn't say what type `x` is, the compiler doesn't recognize that it would need to autobox to make everything consistent.

Comment: Works for me, too, albeit on Java 8.

Comment: @chrylis, the compiler should infer the type of `x` (as `Integer`) from the type of the second argument to `register.apply()`.  Having done so, it should not hesitate to unbox `x`.  And for me, it does.

Comment: Can not reproduce. Can you post details about your setup? Which java? Which IDE? Maybe some non-standard compiler? Like the eclipse compiler? Could be a bug. It should be able to infer the type on its own and unbox.

Comment: i'm using intellij CE edition 2019.1.2 and OpenJDK 11.0.1 on a macbook. Yes i thought so too that it could infer, i think it has to do something with the boxing/unboxing and it might be a bug.

Comment: Can't reproduce using OpenJDK 11.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oleksandr example:

```
register.apply(0, (Integer x) -> x & 6);
```

Does not work, compiler gives me:

> incompatible types in lambda expression, Expected Object but found Integer

This does work:

```
register.apply(0, x -> (x & 6));
```

By explicitly telling it to perform the bitwise operation first and then return **(i still can't explain why this works and not without but now it works)**

But the best solution was to use the `IntUnaryOperator` interface that i wasn't even aware of suggested by RealSkeptic in the comments above.

```
public void apply(int index, IntUnaryOperator func) {
    V[index] = func.applyAsInt(V[index]);
}
```

Thanks for your help